# flush() after Hql querie using spring data jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I'm writing some hql queries using the `@Query` annotation in a spring data jpa repository. I know that I can use the methods from the repository interface, but for learning purpose, I'm writing them explicitly.

Here is my Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * if we delete the transactional annotation-> we get an exception
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run( String... args ) throws Exception {
        saveOperation();
        deleteOperationUsingHql();
    }

    private void saveOperation() {
        Person p = new Person("jean", LocalDate.of(1977,12,12));
        personRepository.save(p);
    }

    private void deleteOperationUsingHql() {
        personRepository.deleteUsingHql(1L);
        personRepository.flush();
        Optional<Person> p = personRepository.findById(1L);
        if (p.isPresent()){
            System.out.println("still present");
        }
    }
}
```

My personRepository interface

```
public interface PersonRepository  extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

      @Query(value = "select p from Person p where p.id=?1")
      List<Person> getById( Long id);

      @Modifying
      @Query(value = "delete from Person p where p.id=:id")
      void deleteUsingHql( Long id );
}
```

The person class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private LocalDate date;

   // constructors,getters...omitted for brievety
}
```

everything is running well, but for the `deleteOperationUsingHql()`, even If I deleted the person from the database and even if I flush the modification to the database, the person with `id=1` is still returned by the `findById(1L)` method. What should I do for making the `findById(1L)` returning an empty Optional.

My second question is about the `@Transactional` annotation, I know how it works in details, but I don't know why if we delete it, We get the following exception

> Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing
>   an update/delete query

Could someone explains why I'm getting this exception when `@Transactional` is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even If I deleted the person from the database and even if I flush the modification to the database, the person with id=1 is still returned by the findById(1L) method

That's normal, because you use a query to delete the person, instead of actually using the repository (and thus the EntityManager) delete method. Queries bypass the session cache completely, so Hibernate has no idea that this person has been deleted, and returns the instance in its cache. Solution: don't use a query. Alternate solution, clear the cache after deleting (for example by setting the `clearAutomatically`flag of the `Modifying` annotation to true).

> Could someone explains why I'm getting this exception when @Transactional is removed.

Because when `@Transactional` is removed, there is no transaction being started by SPring before executing the method, and as you can see from the error message, delete queries must be executed inside a transaction.

Comment: Now, I understand clearly, just for the @Transactional annotation, for some other operations there is no exception thrown, should I understand that there are some operations that dosen't need to run in a transaction.